# Parent links in HATEOAS

Tags: rest, hateoas

I am new to REST and HATEOAS and trying to create a simple API.

I have a simple one to many parent child relationship.

I have created the api as follows:

Parents: `http://example.com/api/parents`

Parent: `http://example.com/api/parents/123`

Children of Parent: `http://example.com/api/parents/123/children`

Child of Parent: `http://example.com/api/parents/123/children/456`

I am now adding hypermedia links to all of the responses.

Each response has a `self` link and the `parent` responses have a `children` link.

Should I add a `parent` link to the `child` responses?

If the resource was located at `http://example.com/api/children/456` then of course it will need the link.

But this is specifically where the link is to a parent in the child's resource address.

i.e. `http://example.com/api/parents/123` is a substring of `http://example.com/api/parents/123/children/456`

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you should use the HAL Rest Standard:

https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/halprimer

You have the links to your subresource in in the main resource.
And HATEOS supports HAL, you won't have to do by hand

Comment: so, according to the HAL standard, the children urls would always be from the root `http://example.com/api/children` and `http://example.com/api/children/456` and never as a sub url of the parent?

Comment: but what about when you want the children of a parent - should that be done using querystring filtering?